# Django admin Many2Many widget customization

Tags: django, django-admin

I need to customize how the m2m widget for Django Admin gets displayed but I am kind of stumped where to start. I have tried subclassing couple of widgets from `django.forms` and `django.contrib.admin.wigets` but nothing seems to be working.

Here's a depiction of what I am looking for https://i.stack.imgur.com/81AY3.png.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like the kind of thing that could be achieved with JavaScript alone. For adding your own JavaScript to the Django admin, see the documentation for [ModelAdmin media definitions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. It does most of the work. However, the list does not get updated when a new item is added and changing an item does not redirect back to the original page.

/your_app/forms.py

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Media:
        js = ('js/custom_m2m.js',)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

/your_media/js/custom_m2m.js

```
django.jQuery(function() {
    var $ = django.jQuery;

    // Add a new place holder div to hold the m2m list
    $('div.options div').append('<div class="newdiv"></div>');

    // Assign some variables
    var target = "options"; // <-- Target Field
    var newdiv = $('div.newdiv');
    var next_page = window.location.pathname;
    var add_link = $('div.'+target+' div a#add_id_'+target);
    var edit_img = "/static/media_admin/img/admin/icon_changelink.gif";
    var add_img = "/static/media_admin/img/admin/icon_addlink.gif";

    // Make the placeholder div bit nicer
    newdiv.attr("style", "line-height:20px; margin-left:105px;");

    // Iterate through select options and append them to 'newdiv'
    $('select#id_'+target+' option[selected="selected"]').each(function() {
        newdiv.append('<a href="/admin/shop/option/'+$(this).val()+'/?next='+next_page+'">'+$(this).text()+' <img src="'+edit_img+'" /></a><br />');
    });

    // Add a 'Add new' link after the option list
    add_link.html('<strong>Add new</strong> ' + add_link.html());
    add_link.appendTo(newdiv);

    // Show the 'newdiv' and hide the original dropdown
    $('select#id_'+target).after(newdiv);
    $('select#id_'+target).css("display", "none");
    $('div.'+target+' p[class="help"]').css("display", "none");
});
```

As you can see, the above script uses some hardcoded paths. Any improvement would be helpful.